# Visualforce: Control checkbox's default value

Tags: visualforce, default-value

So I'm trying to Embed a VF page on my Incoming_Payment__c object, that will allow connecting a few opportunities to it. I want to:

1. Show all opportunities related to the same account (Works!)

***2. If opportunity is already connected to the payment, show the checkbox as checked (my current problem)***

1. Add a button that would connect the opportunities based on page selection (my future problem, didn't get to this yet but I'm noting it so it would be clear that I need the user to be able to be able to change the default value)

I can't see how I can control the checkbox value based on attributes in my controller (I can easily find the ones that are supposed to be checked, but how do I tell the page that?)

**My page:**

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Incoming_Payment__c" extensions="vfAddOppsToPayment" >
<apex:pagemessages id="errmsg"/>  <apex:form >
<apex:outputPanel id="main">
<table>
<tr>
 <apex:repeat value="{!headers}" var="h">
  <td class="hdr">{!h}</td>
 </apex:repeat>
</tr>
<apex:repeat value="{!Opps}" var="a">
 <tr>
  <td ><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.id}" selected="true" /></td>
  <td>"{!a.name}" </td>
  <td>"{!a.Account.name}" </td>
  </tr>
</apex:repeat>
</table>    </apex:outputPanel>
 </apex:form>   
 </apex:page>
```

**My Controller:**

public with sharing class vfAddOppsToPayment {

```
public vfAddOppsToPayment(ApexPages.StandardController controller)   {

//this.MonthlyReport = (Monthly_Report__c)controller.getSubject();   this.payment =    (Incoming_Payment__c)controller.getrecord();   payment
= [select id, Account__c from Incoming_Payment__c p where id=:payment.id ];       this.ViableOpps = [ SELECT Id,Invoice_Receipt__c, name, Account.name, AccountId 
                    FROM Opportunity o WHERE o.AccountId = :payment.Account__c ];   }

 // public Getter to provide table headers

  public string[] getheaders() { 

   return new string []   {'Related','Opportunity Name','Account'} ;
     }


  // public Getter to get child list

   public Opportunity[] getOpps() {

   return this.ViableOpps;

   }
     // class variables

   Incoming_Payment__c  payment;

   Opportunity[] ViableOpps;

  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How I would set this up is by way of a wrapper class. Here's a nifty trick that uses a Set to determine the state of each checkbox that's lightweight, and has the bonus of providing you with a populated Set of selected records for your controller to use automatically.

```
public with sharing class vfAddOppsToPayment {

    public vfAddOppsToPayment(ApexPages.StandardController controller)   {
        //this.MonthlyReport = (Monthly_Report__c)controller.getSubject();   
        payment = (Incoming_Payment__c)controller.getrecord();   
        payment = [select id, Account__c from Incoming_Payment__c p where id=:payment.id ];       
        ViableOpps = [SELECT Id,Invoice_Receipt__c, name, Account.name, AccountId 
                        FROM Opportunity o WHERE o.AccountId = :payment.Account__c];
        selectedOpps = new Set<Id>();

        // HERE:: Determine which opps to select by default simply by adding their ID to selectedOpps
    }

    // public Getter to provide table headers
    public string[] getheaders() { 
        return new string [] {'Related','Opportunity Name','Account'} ;
    }

    // public Getter to get child list
    public OpportunityWrapper[] getOpps() {
        OpportunityWrapper[] items = new OpportunityWrapper[0];
        for(Opportunity record: ViableOpps) {
            items.add(new OpportunityWrapper(this, record));
        }
        return items;
    }

    // class variables
    Incoming_Payment__c  payment;
    Opportunity[] ViableOpps;
    Set<Id> selectedOpps;

    // Wrapper class
    public class OpportunityWrapper {
        public OpportunityWrapper(vfAddOppsToPayment controller, Opportunity record) {
            this.controller = controller;
            this.record = record;
        }
        vfAddOppsToPayment controller;
        public Opportunity record { get; set; }
        public Boolean isSelected { 
            get { 
                return controller.selectedOpps.contains(record.Id); 
            }
            set { 
                if(value)
                    controller.selectedOpps.add(record.Id);
                else
                    controller.selectedOpps.remove(record.Id);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you simply change your page as follows:

```
<apex:page standardcontroller="Incoming_Payment__c" extensions="vfAddOppsToPayment" >
<apex:pagemessages id="errmsg"/>  <apex:form >
<apex:outputPanel id="main">
<table>
<tr>
 <apex:repeat value="{!headers}" var="h">
  <td class="hdr">{!h}</td>
 </apex:repeat>
</tr>
<apex:repeat value="{!Opps}" var="a">
 <tr>
  <td ><apex:inputCheckbox value="{!a.isSelected}" /></td>
  <td>"{!a.record.name}" </td>
  <td>"{!a.record.Account.name}" </td>
  </tr>
</apex:repeat>
</table>    </apex:outputPanel>
 </apex:form>   
 </apex:page>
```

Comment: Looks good! but it seems the wrapper class doesn't get the values from controller.selectedOpps - that always comes up as null.

Comment: Worked great in the end - Thanks! I just forgot to add "this." when defining "selectedOpps"